# How can I pass an event from Application to Activity in Android?

Tags: android, listener, handler

I've got a little gap in my knowledge here and I want to make sure I do it right before writing all the wrong code.

I have an Android app that extends **Application** to set up some core functions for a TCP client. There are a few different **Activity** screens that should interact with **Application**. What I'm stuck on, is what to do when a data packet is received by **Application**. I want to relay it to the currently-visible **Activity**, whatever it is.

Coming from a C# background, I'd just create an Event in the **Application**, and simply subscribe to that event when an **Activity** is created. But I'm getting confused with Java Listeners, Handlers, ...

What's the best way to go about that? Should I be doing a Service instead? (But I don't really care if the TCP connection is killed when the app is not shown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a `LocalBroadcastManager` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)) approach.

Create one of those puppies in your `Application` class, and register/unregister your `Activity` objects in `onStart` and `onStop`. See `Context.registerReceiver`. Note that this requires using `Intent`s, which might be too restrictive/heavy-weight for your application; packing/unpacking data can be a chore.

Alternatively, you don't have to use any specific android class to do it--just keep track of what `Activity` your program is in by calls to your `Application` in `onStart` and `onStop`. Might help clean your code if you make all of your activities-of-interest extend a subclass of `Activity` that contains this logic.

Comment: I think your second idea is probably fine for this. Would I store a handle for the "current" activity in a Context variable and then call the Handler for that Context when I have data? Are those the right terms?

Comment: I'd go one step further and store it as an `Activity`, as then you have access to a couple more methods that might be useful, especially when coming from a background service (e.g. `Activity.runOnUiThread`). That way, there's no need for a `Handler`.

Comment: Already works like a champ. Using runOnUiThread as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I was battling with this in my application, and seeing this question made me question my own (convoluted) approach and trade it for this simpler one.